# How to direct to another web page when "Buy Now" button is clicked in ecommerce frontend?

Tags: event-observer, action

How to direct to another web page when "Buy Now" button is clicked in ecommerce frontend magento? I am doing mobile apps and accessing my website webpages by using android webview. What I want to know is "Is there a way to direct to another custom webpage when Buy Now button is clicked with the condition if the url contains www.example.com?"

For example

if(buynow button is clicked)
{
   if(url == "www.aa.com")
   {
      go to my custom page
   }
   else
   {
      original page
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `a module and trigger a event` when `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event call.

Create module:**app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
                </custommodule>
            </models>
        <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers> 
                <myredirect>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>myredirect</method>
                </myredirect>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

2)Observer.php `(app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model)`

code is

```
public function myredirect($observer){
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"www.aa.com")==true):
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])->sendResponse();
        exit;
        endif;
    }
    }
```

3)create module control file **Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/Amit_Custommodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: By the way, do you know how to hide header and footer in every pages. I want to hide header and footer in every pages if it is mobile. I want to show header and footer if it is web. Because I am calling data from web for my mobile apps by using webview. In my mobile apps webview, it shows header and footer because I am directly calling web pages. Do you know how to hide header and footer if it is calling from mobile?